# How to Change the Color Scheme in a Docx document?

Tags: c#, ms-office

I want to know if it is possible to modify the colors of a document programatically using C#.

[image]

After generating a document using the C# language, how can I modify the document theme color? I have tried to do it using a macro but that didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem was:

1. Save the desired theme in the thmx format;
2. Create the following macro:

   Sub MacroSetTheme()

   ```
    ActiveDocument.ApplyDocumentTheme _ "C:\Users\Admin\Theme.thmx"

    ActiveDocument.Save
   ```

   End Sub

Comment: Can that Color be set without applying the full theme? I can't see a way of doing this.

Answer (score -1):

The Word object model is common for all kind of applications - VBA, C#, Visual Basic and etc. I'd suggest recording a VBA macro using the macro recorder available in Word. Thus, you will find the properties and methods that should be used to get the job done programmatically. See [Record or run a macro](http://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Record-or-run-a-macro-cd56fb86-d8b2-475c-ba39-9728389feeeb) for more information.

Also you may find how to automate Word using C# reading/learning the following materials:

- [How to automate Microsoft Word to create a new document by using Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316384)
- [C# app automates Word (CSAutomateWord3)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateWord-f422cae5)

Comment: Unhelpful. The macro recorder doesn't record anything when the Document Color is changed.